# How would I go about making a pixel based game?

Tags: lua, pixel

Something like galaga! I have no idea where to start. I know how to program, I have an environment to make the game, and I can create all the pixel/tiles on the screen. I just don't really know where to go after that. I've looked online for help but with no luck.

Any feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: How is that related to Lua?

Comment: That is the language I would be writing it in.

Comment: Try https://love2d.org.

Comment: Can you give me some tips regarding my original question? Techniques for making a game similar to galaga?

Comment: This is too broad a question.

Comment: First step is to find and read some pixel-game tutorials, of which there are many. See what others have done, and how (rendering/timing, collision detection, world modeling, etc) and limitations there are. Then use that knowledge to "make" something.

Comment: There are many game libraries, and there are many lists of game libraries. [Wikipedia has an article on them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines) which you might find helpful. In Lua, I've used [LÖVE](http://love2d.org/) before, while I was learning to code, and it was terrific to use, so I highly recommend that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No matter what language you code in, I would start by making a diagram describing the game flow.  If you break it into small pieces, you'll find yourself following that process as you start to code.

Ask yourself:

1. What is happening in the game? (Aliens attacking a single ship)
2. What is the object of the game? (Destroy each successive wave of aliens without getting nuked.)
3. What controls are necessary to accomplish this? (firing button, movements, any specials you might incorporate.)
4. what sorts of power-ups / extra lives will be available and when?
5. What is the reward schema (more points / power-ups for higher-level kills, etc.)
6. What is the derivative increase in difficulty? (is it linear - gets a bit harder each level or, does it get increasingly difficult by greater amounts as you pass levels - also, do you want to build in respite levels where it chills for a level or two.)

Hopefully, you get the idea - just chop up the project into bite-sized chunks before you write your first line, follow your process, and adjust as necessary - a couple of hours of planning could save you many hours of dithering while trying to code a project you have not really defined for yourself.

I hope this helps
~b

Comment: Thanks dude! This'll help a bunch, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

A great alternative would be to use Löve2D, it is a game framework that uses Lua as its programming language and it is very easy to use.